# What is the best way to include links in presentations?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am creating a presentation in Google Slides that requires that I use a link for a usable web-demo at a specified URL. However, any attempt I make at inserting a hyperlink into my document looks horrific (what with the default link styling). I am very particular about my graphic design on this sort of thing.

I haven't been able to find a source online that addresses this problem, and I haven't come up with a solution any more elegant than having a slide dedicated to having a large clickable textbox that just says "DEMO".

So what is the best way to include a link in a slide-based presentation?

Has anybody else run into this issue before? Or should I perhaps consider a better medium for presenting?

Edit: Google -slides- not google sheets

Comment: Well, I writed an answer for Google Sheets too, but Do you mean Google sheets, Google Slides, or Power Point?

Answer (score 2):

On Google Docs. Using the Google Slides. (This also works with PowerPoint and Excel)

1. Insert a nice element, image, or text you want to add a hyperlink.
2. Right click on it and you will see the link option.
3. Paste a link in the dialog box.
4. Now, when you run the presentation that object is now a big button.

---

On Google docs using Sheets

1. Insert a link using the link button on top menu.
2. You can add a text "Demo" and a hyperlink separately and then you can format the cell aligning centering and adding color.

You can edit the link on the formula bar, with something like this:

> =HYPERLINK("http://example.com/","Demo")

---

Normally I am not overexcited about a program. But **a great**, option for PC is SlideDog. https://slidedog.com

This embeds, for example, a PowerPoint, then in the next slide you can have a web page running full page on Chrome, and on the next page you can have a fullscreen video and on the next page a PDF.

All running seamlessly, like this is the daddy of the different elements.

The program uses additional programs to integrate the elements. VLC player, Chrome, Adobe Reader, PowerPoint viewer.

At the moment for Windows only.

Comment: Hi Rafael, I meant to type "google slides", and have corrected the original post. I am not having difficulty getting links into my presentation, but am wondering the best practices for inserting links into software from a graphic design standpoint. Standalone links with just hyperlinked text looks bad and I was looking for an alternative method.

Comment: As the answer states, you can add a hyperlink to an image or shape.